# System of linear equation, is my solution correct?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

[image]

Forgot to mention but $s,r \in \mathbb{R}$

Could someone help me check whether my solution to the problem is sound? Also is there a better way to solve this? This problem was part of my problem set on the topics of “Gauss-jordan elimination” and “Counting solutions to systems of linear equations(SLE) containing unknown constants” but i didn’t use either of this here and didn’t use a matrix at all actually.

Comment: @Moo - $(a,b) = (1,1)$ was among the solutions found. Had the problem required $r,s \ne 0$, it would be the only solution. But (2) shows that it is only one among many solutions.  @ Gnolius - Your solution is sound. You could explain it more clearly, but that is always going to be true, so it isn't worth spending too much time on. There is little you could do which would be "better". Unless forced to do so, it geneally isn't useful to use sledge hammers to swat flies.

Comment: @PaulSinclair thanks for the clarification